# browser.tabs.executescript() is not working in firefox

Tags: cross-browser, firefox-addon, add-on

execting sript in `popup.js`

```
window.browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'page.js'
}, function () {
    //some logic here
});
```

extension is working normal in **chrome**

**firefox** giving me an error **non-structured-clonable data** like below

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Script 'moz-extension://<extension-name>/page.js' result is non-structured-clonable data
```

seen for help [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1339559) but not get an idea please check if you could

i can explain in more detail if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to check for errors in page.js script because if it has any error then promise will reject it